# "Work" vs. "working" (noun)

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns, gerunds

What are the differences between *work* and *working* when used as nouns?

For example:

> Advocates claim that **work/working** brings a lot of benefits for young people.

Which one is correct? I have searched in a dictionary but they are defined with nearly the same meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the difference between saying:

> *Having something to do* has a lot of benefits for young people.

and

> *The act of doing something* has a lot of benefits for young people.

The first corresponds to *work*, the second to *working*.

Comment: Or [Always working and never playing makes Jack a dull boy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_work_and_no_play_makes_Jack_a_dull_boy)

Comment: @FumbleFingers- I keep trying to tell my boss this, but she doesn't seem to care.

Comment: She probably thinks *playing with words/wordplay* here on ELU should be enough to satisfy you!